# How can I open old SPX files?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

The file format Open-SPX is a 3d image format developed by interzart around 2000, and released open source with the GPL. I've got some images in that format, which I want to import into a more modern editing program, but I can't find anything that can open/covert them. I've tried searching online, but it looks like interzart is gone, and I couldn't find any evidence of SPX files.

I'm looking for either a way to convert them to a modern format, or source code or documentation showing how I can write something that can read them.

Answer (score 1):

Legacy formats and software is always a crapshoot, I've found a few leads that might help you.

From an article back in the 2000s "A plug-in for 3D-Studio MAX that allows importing and exporting SPX data into and out of 3D Studio" Maybe try and hunting that down?

[This legacy software might work for you](http://www.parallelgraphics.com/products/vrmlpad/download/)

[Or some of these might.](https://www.web3d.org/x3d/vrml/tools/authoring/)

It looks the the German company that originally developed it changed from Interzart to Scanbull Software around 2006 but I can't seem to find any other information about them.

Their software was 3D Editor Marlin, so unless you get extremely lucky on ebay you might be out of luck.

[This git repository of old software](https://gist.github.com/afiestas/135cc16b2ec7a6cca4a7185b3bb38e2d) has several versions of Dimension 3D-Systems GmbH - Open SPX Plugin which might help.

This was all the information I could find with limited research time, hope it helps!

---

### UPDATE

I might have found a legacy webplugin that could be of use! [See if this helps!](http://wwwalt.med-rz.uniklinik-saarland.de/med_fak/anatomie/bock/3D/hilfe.htm#plugin)